# Locating using id fails but using link it succeeds to click

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

For the following link,

```
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
GNWL200/WL102
<br/>
<a id="17235-SL-GN-0" href="javascript:jpBook($('#17235-SL-GN-0'),'17235','HSRA','SRT','22-9-2017','SL','GN',3,false,0,0,'S');" tabindex="1">Book Now</a>
</td>
```

If I uses the link as shown below, it succeeds to click

```
browser.element(link: "Book Now").click
```

But if I uses the id as shown below it says element is not visible(not present). May I know why?

```
browser.link(:id, "17235-SL-GN-0").click
```

Error

```
Uncaught exception: element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Anchor: located: true; {:id=>"17235-SL-GN-0", :tag_name=>"a"}> to be present
    C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:633:in `raise_present'
    C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:672:in `rescue in element_call'
    C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:684:in `element_call'
    C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.8.4/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:136:in `click'
    C:/Users/rajagopalan.m/RubymineProjects/SeleniumLearning/Rest/TrainTicketBooking.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Is the link visible on the page, or does it have `style="display:none;"`? You may need to pass `visible: false` as a parameter.

Comment: @TomLord Link is visible. No, this style tag is not able `style="display:none;"` , I have attached the corresponding code in the beginning. It's clicking while I use link, but it's not clicking while I use id.  That's why question is!

Comment: Did you confirm there is only one element will be found by:  browser.link(:id, "17235-SL-GN-0") on page?

Comment: @yong Yeah, you got the point, Yes, you are right, there is two element with this id and the first one is not pointing out the element which I wanted to click but second one does but since selenium uses the second one, it fails . Thank you.

Comment: having duplicated ID values technically means your page has INVALID HTML.. at least according to the spec.   most browsers won't care, but it's still not good practice to use invalid html.    if it were me I'd file a bug on that

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden Did you down vote my question?

Comment: nope, wasn't me..   I usually only downvote if a question has neither sample HTML nor sample code that they tried to use (e.g. shows very litte effort and amounts to a 'do my work for me' request)..   yours might have a little funky grammar, but you provide html, code, and the error..   Grammar I wrote off to someone who may not be a native english speaker, and it this is not a creative writing class, so I have no reason to downvote.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden Okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question from @yong comment

Actually there are two element present in the page with same id and the first one is invisible and the second one is actual element which I wanted to click, that's what it's throwing the error.

Here is the html file

```
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
GNWL203/WL105
<br/>
**<a id="17235-SL-GN-0" href="javascript:jpBook($('#17235-SL-GN-0'),'17235','HSRA','SRT','22-9-2017','SL','GN',3,false,0,0,'S');" tabindex="1">Book Now</a>**
</td>
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<span style="font:11px arial;color:red;float:right">* CURR_AVBL : Current Booking Available | RAC : Reservation Against Cancellation | WL # : Wait List | REGRET/WL : No more booking allowed | AVAILABLE : Available | NOT AVAILABLE : Not Available</span>
<br/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="j_idt413" class="rf-p ">
<div id="enqpanelid1" class="rf-p ">
</div>
</span>
<form id="avlAndFareForm" name="avlAndFareForm" method="post" action="/eticketing/trainbetweenstns.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input name="avlAndFareForm" value="avlAndFareForm" type="hidden"/>
<div id="avlAndFareForm:trainSchedPanel" style="visibility: hidden;">
<div id="avlAndFareForm:j_idt480" class="rf-p " style="min-height:383px;width:99%;">
<div id="avlAndFareForm:j_idt480_body" class="rf-p-b ">
<ul id="tabul">
<div id="tabcontent">
<div id="c1" class="container-div">
<div id="j_idt382" class="rf-p ">
<div id="j_idt382_header" class="rf-p-hdr ">
<div id="j_idt382_body" class="rf-p-b ">
<table class="t1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;padding-left: 1em;">
<td style="padding-top:3px" align="center">
GNWL203/WL105
<br/>
**<a id="17235-SL-GN-0" href="javascript:jpBook($('#17235-SL-GN-0'),'17235','HSRA','SRT','22-9-2017','SL','GN',3,false,0,0,'S');" tabindex="1">Book Now</a>**
</td>
```

Comment: We added the visible parameter for cases such as these: `browser.link(id: '17235-SL-GN-0', visible: true).click`

Comment: Also, someone mentioned recently that they were having difficulties locating elements by ids that started with a number (which didn't used to be allowed). I've been meaning to write a spec to check it out, but haven't had time. That might also cause a problem (if you used `element` instead of `link`)

Comment: @titusfortner To your first comment, okay. Actually I have forgotten to use visible locator. And to your second comment, Why using element is problematic while link is not a problem when I use id?

Comment: The former will convert it to xpath in Watir the latter to css in selenium. Oh, but that's only in W3C code which you don't use. Json wire protocol shouldn't matter.

Comment: @titusfortner I know of this very well, That's why I haven't written the code `b.link(text: 'Book Now').click` because it goes on to form the xpath, So I have written this code `b.element(link: 'Book Now').click`, this code uses the selenium locator `link:`  And I don't understand what do you mean by later to css in selenium, what does that mean? Is there somethere WATIR creates the css equivalent? I haven't seen any so far.

Comment: No, both of those translate into XPath (or would if 'link' were a valid parameter). ID is the only one that has a short circuit in the Watir code.

Comment: I'm saying I don't think this has been tested with an id that starts with a number: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb#L547

Comment: @titusfortner OH MY GOD! I am amazed that you do not know! This is absolutely not true. If given locator is available in selenium locator list, WATIR doesn't go to form xpath, If the given locator is not selenium list, then it goes on to form the xpath. So Link locator is available in the selenium list, so it doesn't. Read the condition here `if WD_FINDERS.include?(how) wd_find_first_by(how, what) else find_first_by_multiple end`

Comment: Oh right, yes, that's how it works. I'd forgotten it was a Selenium locator. :) But I still think you are missing out by not having the extra encapsulation since the overhead is minimal.

Comment: @titusfortner 
 
No, you said only id is the only locator does the short circuit. NO again, There are few places b.link(text:'something') won't work but b.element(link: 'something') works properly. And also another advantage is, If more than one link present with the same name, then you are in need of passing visible: true additionally but selenium automatically picks up the visible one when you use link locator.

Comment: @titusfortner  that was me who mentioned the thing about ID values starting with a numeral.  Prior to HTML5 that was not allowed.  It's allowed now, but CSS selection (you can test this easily via browser console) will not work selecting an ID that starts with a numeral unless you 'escape' the first character.  (which is I guess a trick to get around that CSS limitation)   So if your selection method in watir is rendered into a CSS selection under the covers, and selecting by ID, for an ID like the one above, I'd expect it to fail, while rendered to xcopy selection would work.

Answer (score 0):

If link is not visible for regular Click() use jsClick:

```
"arguments[0].click();"
```

I'm not sure how it looks like in Ruby, but C#, Java looks simillar to:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I know that I can click through Javascript, Javascript doesn't check the visibility condition but the question is why selenium click can't be performed on the element using Id locator while it can click through `link` locator.